# Visual studio 2022 not able to install packages from nuget manager

Tags: nuget-package, visual-studio-2022

I am using Visual studio 2022. i am not able to download any package from nuget package manager.
packages are list but when i click to download its says

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

[image]

I modified my visual studio but no luck

Comment: Check [Package sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#package-sources)

Comment: It worked after removing all package sources and adding them again.